# Mysql query to join tables and select only the rows that are not null and that have equal ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

I have 10 tables. 1 of the tables is sort of the "hub." The others are used to identify specific attributes. The hub table contains every id while the other tables only carry the ids that are necessary for that table.

I need a join query that can join all rows in the hub table with all of the rows in any of the sub tables according to the id.

So for instance, if one of the rows in the hub table has an id of 9 and one of the sub tables has an id of 9, it should join them. It should not join rows that don't exist and can't contain columns that are null.

I'm using Zend-Framework to peice this together, but i'll be happy to receive advice on how to do this in either zend-framework or standard php/sql.

This is an example of what I am using now that is NOT working. This query grabs the necessary info but also includes null rows. In addition to that, it nulls out the id in the sub table row, which I need.

```
$select = $this->db->select()
     ->from("widgets")
     ->joinLeft("widget_login", "widgets.id = widget_login.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_admin", "widgets.id = widget_admin.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_text", "widgets.id = widget_text.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_image", "widgets.id = widget_image.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_facebook", "widgets.id = widget_facebook.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_twitter", "widgets.id = widget_twitter.id")
     ->joinLeft("widget_google", "widgets.id = widget_google.id");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should append to your query:

```
->where('(not(widgets_login is null)) and (not(widgets_admin is null)) and ... (The same here for all your tables);
```

Comment: Appending a where statement could be the answer but I'm not sure if this is it. The syntax for the the statement may be wrong cause when I add that the result is completely null.

Comment: Did you try to run a plain SQL query written by yourself (like the one you're trying to automatically build) and look what it returns? Sometimes it's correct that returns `null` just because there is another logic mistake/bug just in the data we're querying :).